# How to use the method setPixels(rectangle, byteArray) of bitmapData in Adobe Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, adobe, arrays

```
Error #2030: End of file was encountered.
```

This method is not working

I am using it like this

```
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba = bmd.getPixels(bmd.rect);

bmd.setPixels(srcRect, ba);
bm.bitmapData = bmd;

img.source = bm;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the possition of your Byte Array (ba.position = 0) before re-using it

```
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba = bmd.getPixels(bmd.rect);

ba.position = 0;
bmd.setPixels(srcRect, ba);
bm.bitmapData = bmd;

img.source = bm;
```